# What's the difference between .deploy() vs. .deployed()

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I am writing a script for a smart contract that I'll deploy using hardhat.
I'm confused on the difference between .deploy() and .deployed(), what does each one do?

```
    const main = async () => {
  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('WavePortal');
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
  await waveContract.deployed();
  console.log('Contract addy:', waveContract.address);
...
```

Comment: You will find your answer just here: [enter link description here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117885/differences-between-deploy-and-deployed-methods/117887#117887)

Answer (score 0):

`deploy()` will trigger this deployment of the contract and `deployed()` checks if the contract is already available on the blockchain and if the deployment is still ongoing will wait for the deployment transaction to be mined.